# Nptel-pascal programming assignment

Tags: c

i am pursuing the course on programming and data structures in nptel's MOOC.
A programming assignment in the course requires us to calculate sum of selected coefficients. 
Now the program i wrote calculated the answer , but i am experiencing a runtime error.
Now i had this inclination of using gets() instead of scanf() so as to speed up my input.
how do i do that?
the code is as follows:

```
    #include<stdio.h>


int combi(int ,int);
 long fact(int);
 int main()
         {
              int r,i,v[20],p[20],t,l=1,b=0,sum=0,a=0,flag=0;
      char ch='a';

scanf("%d",&r);


scanf("%d",&t);

for(i=0;i<t;i++)
{

         scanf("%d",&v[0]);
         if(getchar()==' ')
            {
                if(r<v[0])
                {
                    while(ch!='\n')
                    {

                        scanf("%d",&v[l]);
                        l++;
                        if(getchar()=='\n')
                        {
                            p[a]=-1;
                            a++;
                            l=1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                  while(ch!='\n')
                    {

                        scanf("%d",&v[l]);
                        if(v[l]>v[0])
                          {
                                flag=1;

                          }
                        l++;
                        if(getchar()=='\n')
                        {

                            if(flag>0)
                            {
                                 p[a]=-1;
                                 a++;
                                 l=1;
                                 sum=0;
                        flag=0;
                                 break;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                for(b=1;b<l;b++)
                                {
                                    sum=sum+combi(v[0],v[b]);
                                }
                                p[a]=sum;
                                a++;
                                sum=0;
                                l=1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

              }
          }
}

  for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
      printf("%d\t ",p[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
int combi(int x,int y)
{
     int a=fact(x)/(fact(x-y)*fact(y));

     return a;
}
long fact(int z)
{
    int i=1;
    long f=1;
    while(i<=z)
    {
      f=f*i;
      i++;
    }

    return f;
 }
```

Comment: suggestion: never use `gets()`. use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: will it improve runtime?

Comment: how do you suggest i change to fgets?

Comment: for that you need to elaborate `but i am experiencing a runtime error`

Comment: Apparently, he wants to speed it up so that it gets to the error more quickly

Comment: i'm pursuing a course , where the online judge is using the code against test cases. during execution , it is throwing a runtime error

Comment: Your program does not take long for the sample input `6\n
4\n
7 1 2 2 3\n
5 0 1 1 4\n
4 2 3 2\n
6 4 5 3 2 1`. Which input leads to the time error? - Forget about the `(f)gets()`, they will make no noticeable runtime difference.